# validate method always return false even if the data is correct and valid [Yii2]

Tags: php, yii2

**Target**:
I want to create a record after I find out that model is valid otherwise get back to model form page with validation errors.

**Problem**:
validation always returns false. Even all rules are proper. I have tried to make mistake in my rules by adding fields that are not existing still I get no validation errors at all.

**Scenario**:
Form gets validated fine, fields are validated as they should be. When I hit submit after entering valid input (every field is valid), the values get in $model->attributes get just as they should be. But when it comes to validating that model in my controller, $model->validate() always return false.

Here is my code for workaround:

**My View File (_form.php)**:

```
   <div class=''>
        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                'options' => [
                    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
                ],
                'id' => 'create-company-form',
                'layout' => 'horizontal',
                'fieldConfig' => [
                    'template' => "{label}{input}{error}",
                    'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'control-label'],
                ],
        ]); ?>

            <?php echo $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['autofocus' => true, 'placeholder'=> \Yii::t('main', 'Name')]); ?>
            <?php echo $form->field($model, 'idcompanytype')->dropDownList(CompanyType::listCompanyTypesDropDown(), ['prompt'=> \Yii::t('main', 'Select Company Type')]); ?>
            <?php echo $form->field($model, 'datecreation')->textInput(['type'=>'text','format'=>'php:Y-m-d',  'placeholder'=> \Yii::t('main', 'Enter Date')]); ?>


            <?php echo $form->field($model, 'phone')->textInput(['placeholder'=> \Yii::t('main', 'Phone 1')]); ?>
            <?php echo $form->field($model, 'phone2')->textInput(['placeholder'=> \Yii::t('main', 'Phone 2')]); ?>

            <?php echo $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['type'=>'email', 'placeholder'=> \Yii::t('main', 'Email Address')]); ?>
            <?php echo $form->field($model, 'email2')->textInput(['type'=>'email', 'placeholder'=> \Yii::t('main', 'Email Address 2')]); ?>

            <?php echo $form->field($model, 'link')->textInput(['placeholder'=> \Yii::t('main', 'Link 1')]); ?>
            <?php echo $form->field($model, 'link2')->textInput(['placeholder'=> \Yii::t('main', 'Link 2')]); ?>

            <?php echo $form->field($model, 'identification')->textInput(['placeholder'=> \Yii::t('main', 'Identification')]); ?>
            <?php echo $form->field($model, 'identification2')->textInput(['placeholder'=> \Yii::t('main', 'Identification 2')]); ?>


            <?php echo $form->field($model, 'isdefault')->checkbox([
//              'template' => "<div class=\"checkbox checkbox-success\">{input} {label}</div>\n<div class=\"col-lg-8\">{error}</div></div>",
// remove last div and validation gets applied
            ]) ?>

            <?php echo $form->field($model, 'form_image')->fileInput([
                'class'=>'form_image_field',
                'data-allowed_extensions' => \Yii::$app->params['allowedImageExtensions'],
                'data-allowed_MimeTypes' => \Yii::$app->params['allowedImageMimeTypes'],
                'data-allowed_file_size' => \Yii::$app->params['allowedFileSize'],
                'data-upload_url' => Url::toRoute(['document/upload-company-logo']),
            ]); ?>
            <?php echo $form->field($model, 'image')->hiddenInput(['class'=>'form-control file_name_field'])->label(false);?>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='col-12 col-sm-10 offset-sm-1 col-md-8 offset-md-2 col-lg-6 offset-lg-3 col-xl-4 offset-xl-4'>
                    <?php echo Html::submitButton(\Yii::t('main', 'Save'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light m-r-10', 'name' => 'create-button']) ?>
                    <?php echo Html::a(\Yii::t('main', 'Cancel'), ['/company'], ['class' => 'btn btn-dark waves-effect waves-light']); ?>
                </div>
            </div>

        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    </div>
```

**My Model Class (rules(), beforeValidate() methods)**:

```
    public $idcompany;
    public $name;
    public $idcompanytype;
    public $datecreation;
    public $identification;
    public $identification2;

    public $phone;
    public $phone2;

    public $email;
    public $email2;

    public $link;
    public $link2;

    public $isdefault;

    public $created;
    public $updated;
    public $image;

    public $form_image;



    /**
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     * @see \yii\base\Model::rules()
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'idcompanytype', 'datecreation', 'identification', 'email', 'phone', 'link'], 'required'],
            [['image', 'name', 'link', 'link2', 'identification', 'identification2', 'phone', 'phone2'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            [['idcompany', 'idcompanytype', 'created', 'updated'], 'integer'],
            [['datecreation1'], 'date', 'format'=>'php:Y-m-d'],
            [['email', 'email2', ], 'email'],
//          [['isdefault'], 'boolean'],

            [['form_image'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty'=>true, 'extensions' => \Yii::$app->params['allowedImageExtensions'], 'mimeTypes' => \Yii::$app->params['allowedImageMimeTypes']],
        ];
    }


    public function beforeValidate()
    {
        if(null == $this->idcompany){ // case: record does not exists
            $this->created = time();
        }

        $this->updated = time();
    }
```

**Controller Class - actionCreate()**:

```
$model = new Company();

if( $model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post())){ // postback callback
    if( $model->validate() ){
        if( Company::create($model) ){
            \Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', \Yii::t('main', ConstantHelper::TEXT_CREATE_SUCCESS));
            return $this->redirect(['/company']);
        }
        else{
            // throw exception or whatever
        }
    }
    else{
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($model['attributes']); //I get all attributes in attributes array but no error at all
        exit;
        return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model]);
    }
}
else{
    return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

I have no idea why I get no validation at all.
Please let me know If I'm missing something.

**Note**:
I am extending my model with \yii\base\model.

Comment: do you have any scenarios defined for the model? and please share us all of your model class.

Comment: I might be wrong but I think that there is no such method `errors()` in model, I think you can get errors accessing property `$model->errors` or calling method `getErrors()` on it

Comment: as @ArtOsi said, there is no `errors()` method in the model class, unless you defined it manually ! https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model

Comment: And also you checking in if statement if model is loaded `$model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()` so if it returns "false" then you just render your view file again and don't get any errors I believe

Comment: What is your request data (`\Yii::$app->request->post()`)? Can you please update post

Comment: @Mohammad no I have no scenario defined at all

Comment: I am using yii\base\model error message. my model extends base model

Comment: @ArtOsi I get my post data, I am able to store given info in my model but not able to validate it.
looks like my rules dont work at all

Comment: If you extend \yii\base\Model and add the errors() method, it doesn't return the error message you expect. You can try to call the getErrors() method directly to get the error message. If you get it, you may need to check your errors(), otherwise your rule configuration may be wrong.

Comment: @Luna I already think there is something wrong with my rules config. I know that everything else is just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why but adding the following line by the closing of `beforeValidate()` method seems to have fixed this issue for me.

```
return parent::beforeValidate();
```

I think the reason might be because I was not returning updated rules for model to process for validations of model data.

Still, no idea. but it helped.

Comment: This is expected - `beforeValidate()` needs to return `true` in on order to process actual validation. This is documented in method description: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#beforeValidate()-detail

Comment: Also you need to call `parent::beforeValidate()` to trigger `EVENT_AFTER_VALIDATE` event, so you should always  call parent methods when you're overriding some standard `before` or `after` methods.